# Meaning of declaration in JS - [[0]]

Tags: javascript, double, declaration, brackets

Does anybody know what is the meaning of this declaration in JS:
**var m = [[0]];**
I mean what is declarated as type, and why the zero is in the brackets?

Comment: It's an array holding an array holding a single number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[0] is an array with the first index is equal to 0

[[0]] Is an array with its first index equal to an array (whos first index is 0)

It would probably be easier to imagine if you had more elements and space it a bit better:

```
var m = [[0,1,2],[2,4,5],[1,3]]
```

so

```
m[0] = [0,1,2];
m[1] = [2,4,5];
m[2] = [1,3];
```

This can then be expanded for however many dimensions you need leading to collections of collections of collections.

you can then access each index and use it as the array your referencing for instance:

```
m[0].push(4);
m[2].join(',');
```

etc.

(as mentioned above) You can also then access it shorthand like:

```
m[0][0]
m[x][y]
m[n-1][m[0][1]]
```

Making it as complicated or simple as you need.

Answer (score 2):

m has been declared as an array, with a nested array inside it, and the nested array contains a single element - 0

`console.log(m[0][0])` will output `0`